# Allow repository access only to collaborators who use SSH for authentication on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I don't want my code to be accessible to developers who do not use SSH and instead use password for authentication. Is it possible to do on GitHub?

Comment: No, you can't control how GitHub handles authentication. You can only assign roles to collaborators. Whether they authenticate via ssh, username/password, api token, etc, you can't tell.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot do this.  However, if your goal is to prevent access by weak passwords and your repository is in an organization, you can require all organization members to have 2FA enabled.

Once that's the case, users will either have to use a token or an SSH key and will not be able to use a plain password.